# Specify logback.xml to Eclipse JUnit runner

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, logback

I would like to tell to Eclipse JUnit runner which `logback.xml` it should use.
The following conf only works when `Surefire` run the tests:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <logback.configurationFile>path/to/logback.xml</logback.configurationFile>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I know I can just drop a `logback.xml` in `src/test/resources` but I don't want to have a copy of `logback.xml` file in each Maven project.

Any one to help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse run/test launch configurations can pass additional arguments to both the class under test and the VM running the test.
Open the run configuration for your unit test (Right click-> Run configurations...)
Under the Arguments tab add `-Dlogback.configurationFile=path/to/logback.xml` to the VM arguments to tell logback where the configuration file is.

Note: If you want the Run Configuration to be saved (e.g. want to share it with other people, in case Eclipse forgets), go to the Common tab and in the "save as" section select "Shared" and give it a location.

Comment: The following doesn't work:
`<argLine>-Dlogback.configurationFile=path/to/logback.xml</argLine>`

Comment: Thanks for edit but I don't want this conf to be IDE specific :/

Comment: But your question is about Eclipse JUnit runner... perhaps more info on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right (the topic is a bit old, I forgot what I was looking for). I'd like the Eclipse junit runner logback conf to be in source code (thanks to m2e maybe ?), to avoid the need for each dev to setup its Eclipse.

Comment: Saving the launch configuration actually creates a .launch file that then you can add to your VCS and everyone will share.

Comment: I would be better if devs don't have to do anything to make it work.